# Forcing version 2 on remote session for SharePoint management using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

It seems that SharePoint 2010 is still incompatible with PowerShell version 3.0.

I am already aware that it is possible to force compatibility by executing PowerShell with the `-v 2` switch, but is there a way to force this compatibility mode when using a remote session via PSSession as using a remote desktop is quite impractical just to launch a shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>If you start the client PowerShell with `-v 2`. Then outgoing remote sessions should use v2 on the remote end automatically.</strike>

**Update**: it appears I am mistaken - I think in fact I had discussed this with the PowerShell team, but apparently it's not fixed. Anyway, you can create a session configuration on the server that is forced to version 2.0:

```
PS> $psversiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18010
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16434
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2

PS> Register-PSSessionConfiguration -PSVersion '2.0' -Name "powershell2"
```

Accept all of the prompts. Now, you must pass the name of the new remote session configuration when invoking from the client side (in this example, the client and server are the same machine: my desktop)

```
PS> icm localhost -ConfigurationName powershell2 { $psversiontable }

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
BuildVersion                   6.1.7600.16385
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
PSVersion                      2.0
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.6400
WSManStackVersion              2.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

As you can see, the remote endpoint is running 2.0.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I might add that for me I received the error `Cannot bind parameter 'PSVersion'. Cannot convert value "2" to type "System.Version". Error: "Version string portion
was too short or too long."` but using `-PSVersion '2.0'` worked fine.