# Remote execution of Powershell Version 2 using C#

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I am writing a C# application that triggers execution of a powershell script on a remote server.

The machine where the execution is called from (local dev box) has Powershell Version 2, Version 3, And Version 4 installed as per displayed by $PSVersionTable.PSVersion, on the server, the result is the same.

I ran my code on a test server and it works fine when using V4.0

The issue im having is that on the actual server the commands need to run as a powershell V2.0 and not a V4.0.

I created a New-PSSessionConfigurationFile and then i used Registe-rPSSessionConfiguration to resister the version 2.0 configuration, then i ran Enable-PSRemoting and i set to enable it,  and i selected No to all configurations that are NOT v2.0.

But now when i run the scripts from my dev box, they still report a powershell version 4.0

does anyone know how to force remote powershell execution using version 2.0 and  using C#

this is my Code

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(); 
connectionInfo.ComputerName = computerIdent.ToLowerInvariant();

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
runspace.Open();

StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader("C:\Script\Mysqcript.ps1");
PowerShell psExec = PowerShell.Create();
psExec.Runspace = runspace;
psExec.AddScript(sReader.ReadToEnd()); //reads all the lines in the powershell script

powershellResults = psExec.Invoke();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell - Forcing version 2 on remote session for Sharepoint management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483764/powershell-forcing-version-2-on-remote-session-for-sharepoint-management)

Comment: Unless the new configuration is named `Microsoft.PowerShell` it won't matter if it's the only one available. You'll have to connect to that configuration by name, and I don't see you supplying the name anywhere in the code.

Comment: in my code, how can i specify the configuration i want to use? i been looking how to pass that and i cant find a way to do it. On the remote machine i create a PSSessionConfiguration called Version 2.0

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is on the remote machine I changed the version that the Session Configuration **microsoft.powershell** is using so I ran this command to change that:

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration -name microsoft.powershell -psversion 2.0 -FORCE
```